# Best practice for translations

Tags: java, jsp

I'm writing a website using JSP. I want to have the website available in multiple languages, so I've created a `HashMap` for each language I plan to support, and am finding the text via `map.get("identifier")` (with some other code, of course.)

The problem I'm having is one I've solved before by using a `format`function (similar to `printf` in many languages), but this was in another language.

The problem specifically is that text like `User performed action` may be come `Action was performed by user` in another language (i.e. the terms may become out of order).

In the past, I've done something like `#translate("Welcome to the site, %s!", {"Username"})`, and then used the language's `format` function to replace `%s` with the username. I could simply use `String#replace` but then I can't do something like `#translate("Welcome to the site, %s! You last visited on %s!", {"username", "last visit"})` like I'd like to.

Sorry if this is a bad explanation—just look up `printf` in something like PHP.

What would be the best way to replicate something like this in Java? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you clarify the issue regarding `format`.  The way I've always seen this done is that the identifiers in getLocalizedString(id,language) map to localized strings with the substition tokens e.g., `User performed action %s` or `Action %s was performed by user` and then passed into the format function.  This might be what you're saying but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't reinvent. Use JSTL [`fmt` taglib](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html). It supports [parameterized](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/param.html) messages as well.

```
<fmt:message key="identifier">
  <fmt:param value="${username}" />
</fmt:message>
```

#### See also:

- [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application) - a mini tutorial

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you handle parametric messages with different word orders with `fmt`? All the examples I find are of flat strings.

Comment: @biziclop: you can parameterize as per [MessageFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) rules, i.e. with {0}, {1}, {2}, etc.

Comment: Aaargh, I knew I was missing the obvious. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've stuck myself in that question and I find out that the best way is to use resource bundle like everyone (or almost every one) does. You can use the fmt taglib or the spring message.

I tried to use the gettext solution, but it includes some previous steps (xgettext, msgmerge, msgfmt) which makes this too complex and it is not so good for webapp (in my opinion).

I'm going to use the spring message, you can see an example on:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example.html

Answer (score 0):

use property files to have different languages

```
en_US.properties
fr_CA.properties
```

and in those properties file, have your text like that

```
user.performed.action=User performed an action
```

and then as BalusC said, use JSTL.