# How to escape single quotes for SQL insert...when string to insert is in a user generated variable

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am building an insert command to execute using jdbc. Part of it is to concatenate a user generated string...this all works until the user uses a string like this:

a'bcd

```
String userString="a'bcd";
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO myTable "
                            + "(insertColumn) " 
                            + "VALUES("
                                +"'"+userString+"'"
                                +")";

statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
```

Comment: You need to use paramters.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can do either of the below:

1. Use the **PreparedStatement** class. (*Recommended*)

   ```
   String userString="a'bcd";
   String myStatement = " INSERT INTO MYTABLE (INSERTCOLUMN) VALUES (?)";
   PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement   (myStatement );
   statement.setString(1,userString);
   statement.executeUpdate();
   ```
2. Escape the single quotes.

   In SQL, single quotes will be escaped by using double single quotes. `'` --> `''`

   ```
   String userString="a'bcd";
   String changedUserString = userString.replace("'","''");
           //changedUserString  = a''bcd
   String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO myTable (insertColumn) VALUES("
                           +" '"+changedUserString +"' )";
   ```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from the [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang) library.
Using this you can escape characters from html, xml, <s>sql</s>, etc.  Look for method `escapeXXX` for your purpose.  For reference: [When i need to escape Html string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765766/when-i-need-to-escape-html-string)

note: `escapeSql` was removed in Apache Commons Lang 3 (see [Migrating StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql from commons.lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096614/migrating-stringescapeutils-escapesql-from-commons-lang) which references https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html#StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql)

Eg:

```
String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("input.txt"));
        String results = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(str);
        System.out.println(results);
```

Input:

```
<sometext>
Here is some "Text" that I'd like to be "escaped" for HTML
& here is some Swedish: Tack. Vars?god.
</sometext>
```

Output:

```
&lt;sometext&gt;
Here is some &quot;Text&quot; that I'd like to be &quot;escaped&quot; for HTML
&amp; here is some Swedish: Tack. Vars&aring;god.
&lt;/sometext&gt;
```

Comment: In  StringEscapeUtils  documentationfor for  escapeSQL: "At present, this method only turns single-quotes into doubled single-quotes"

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql is [depreciated](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html).

Comment: This approach only works if you intend to use the input as a HTML output later on. About deprecation, v3.6 of commons-lang is still there and works fine with org.apache.commons.text.[StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option:

Use a native Android method designed for exactly this purpose:

```
DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(String)
```

Here is the documentation for it online:

- [sqlEscapeString() on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String))

The main advantage of using this method, in my opinion, is the self-documentation because of the clear method name.

---

```
String userString="a'bcd";
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO myTable "
                            + "(insertColumn) " 
                            + "VALUES("
                                +"'"+DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(userString)+"'"
                                +")";

statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
```