# Escape characters in SQL without Prepared Statement

Tags: java, sql, spring

I know there are a lot of questions specifically asking this but I'm unsure in my case. I'm using Spring Batch and a FieldSetMapper so I'm generating these statements as strings, and collecting these strings and passing them to my ItemWriter. In this sense, I'm not looking to use a prepared statement. Here's what I've got:

```
private static String insertStmt = "insert into ..." 
//this is the beginning of the insert statement. Not gonna type it all out

private String addStatement() {

    String values = String
            .format("values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' ESCAPE '\'')",
                    this.primCustNum, this.primCustName, this.mfstRptId,
                    this.shtlStpNum, this.primCustAddr1,
                    this.primCustAddr2, this.primCustCity,
                    this.primCustState, this.primCustPostalCde,
                    this.primCustPhoneNum);

    //log.info("INSERT+VALUES: {}", insertStmt + values);
    return insertStmt + values;

}
```

but this won't handle a case like
`insert into ... where values ('tony's place', ...);`
because `tony's` has an apostraphe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look this answer: 
[How to escape single quotes for SQL insert...when string to insert is in a user generated variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331524/how-to-escape-single-quotes-for-sql-insert-when-string-to-insert-is-in-a-user)

You need put two quotes before you send the insertStmt to insert, like this:

- this.primCustNum = this.primCustNum.replace("'","''");

Answer (score -1):

Just create another private method that takes your string as argument and iterate it and if detect special char, it will put a backslash before the char and return new string (with these backslashes). Then, during creating sql statement, instead of plain text, invoke this private method with your text as argument.

Comment: That won't work because in SQL you escape an apostrophe by using two apostrophes, e.g., https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/156501.