# reading strings into a database using sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

So I need to read text files into a sqlite database. I already read the files into an ArrayList called weFeelFine, and now I'm trying to create the database.

creating the database:

```
        try{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);   

        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS +
                " ( "  + COLUMN_LINE + " text " + ")" );    //create a table

        for(int i = 0; i< weFeelFine.size(); i++){
            String line = weFeelFine.get(i);
            insertContacts(statement,line);
        }
        statement.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("something went wrong! " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the INSERT method I use:

```
    private static void insertContacts(Statement statement, String lineNow) throws SQLException{
    statement.execute("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " (" + COLUMN_LINE + " )" +
            "VALUES('" + lineNow + "')" );
}
```

Some sentences contain the  ' symbol. Which causes the a program to fail.

One of the sentences I'm have trouble to read (with words like - i'm ):

```
i'm feeling really grouchy about the weather have an eerie correspondence to the times i've gotten slack around my inner work
```

The error I get:

```
SQL error or missing database (near "m": syntax error)
```

How can I tell the program to ignore that symbol, and take the whole sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't mark the question as a duplicate i'll just leave this link here with a summary.
[How to escape single quotes for SQL insert...when string to insert is in a user generated variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331524/how-to-escape-single-quotes-for-sql-insert-when-string-to-insert-is-in-a-user)

1. You can either use a PreparedStatement:

   `String statement ="INSERT INTO " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " (" + COLUMN_LINE + " ) VALUES(?)";
   PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement(statement);
   statement.setString(1,lineNow);
   statement.executeUpdate();`
2. Escape the Single Quotes usong replace() and then call the insert statement:

   `lineNow = lineNow.replace("'","''");`