# Special chars in JAVA

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, internationalization

สวัสดี Mr.Java Sp'e c'i'a'l'' '

I tried to parse the String using below code but I could't make
simply it shows the wrong value.

```
String s = "สวัสดี Mr.Java Sp'e c'i'a'l'' '"";
s = s.replaceAll("'", "&apos;");
//s = s.replaceAll("'", "''");
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(s);
```

I am trying to get from JSP and save in SQL Server DB and show using JSP and update.
But some times in JSP it shows the converted &apos in jsp as it is instead of Special
Chars.

> Very Simple is Here I have shown this String(สวัสดี Mr.Java Sp'e c'i'a'l'' ') in StackOverflow they
>   save in their DB and Shows and allows me to update this is what I
>   wanted.

Comment: Is it a type or is your string exactly that? Because it's not a valid string, it has a " left alone. You have to remove or escape it.

Comment: It is just for example shown, TYPO, but in Text box of JSP ,this also will be allowed to enter as remark.

Comment: might be it's related to UTF format. might be your db not stored/supported utf format!!.

Comment: no problem wit DB it supports UTF-8 chars.

Answer (score 1):

OK.  So lets look at what your code does:

```
// line 1
String s = "สวัสดี Mr.Java Sp'e c'i'a'l'' '";
```

We have a String with various international characters in it ... and some `"'"` characters.

```
// line 2 
s = s.replaceAll("'", "&apos;");
```

Assuming that those are really `"'"` characters characters, we will replace all instances of `"'"` with an XML / HTML character entity giving us:

```
"สวัสดี Mr.Java Sp&apos;e c&apos;i&apos;a&apos;l&apos;&apos; &apos;"
```

And so ...

```
// line 3
s = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(s);
```

This replaces any active HTML / XML characters with character references.  This includes the ampersand characters `"&"` that you previously inserted.  The result is this:

```
"&#xxxx;&#xxxx;&#xxxx;&#xxxx; Mr.Java Sp&amp;apos;e
 c&amp;apos;i&amp;apos;a&amp;apos;l&amp;apos;&amp;apos; &amp;apos;"
```

(The `&#xxxx;` numeric character references encode those Thai (?) characters.)

When you embed that in an HTML document and display it, you will see "สวัสดี Mr.Java Sp&apos;e c&apos;i&apos;a&apos;l&apos;&apos; &apos;"

---

See what has happened?  You have HTML escaped your HTML escaped apostrophies!!

---

So what do you really need to do?

1. There is no need replace apostrophes with `&apos;`.  Apostrophes are legal in HTML text.
2. There *should be* no need to add HTML escapes so that you can store text in a database:

   - Any modern database will allow you to store Unicode strings without any special encoding.
   - If you are trying to prevent the database's SQL parser getting confused by quotes in the text you are storing, you are doing it the wrong way.  The *right* way to do this is to use a `PreparedStatement`, add parameter placeholders to the query, and use the `PreparedStatement.setXxx` methods to provide the parameter values.  The `execute` (or whatever) will take care of any SQL escaping that needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but what happens if I do this without parse in SQL Server I couldn't insert ' and while show this in jsp text box it become broken text box due to ' .

Comment: As to the `'` problem in SQL (i.e. SQL injection), this is covered by properly using `PreparedStatement`. If you stil have problems with `'` in SQL, then you're apprantely not properly using `PreparedStatement`. As to HTML problem in JSP text box in JSP (i.e. XSS attack), see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948532/where-should-i-escape-html-strings-jsp-page-or-servlets/4948856#4948856. Summarized: do **not** escape them before saving in DB. This makes no utter sense as indicated by Stephen's answer.