# Escape all strings in JSP/Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, escaping

I display strings in my JSP this way:

```
${someString}
```

this string may, of course, contain special html characters. Currently it is possible to HTML-inject malicious code (eg. if someString is a javascript include - `<script src...>`).

**How can I make sure that all strings are escaped before printing?**

I am using Spring MVC and JSP.

Comment: Are u want to execute the tags or remove the tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948532/where-should-i-escape-html-strings-jsp-page-or-servlets

Comment: @newuser I want to escape it, so the user sees `<script` as text in the page.

Comment: @JoshuaMN Use AntySami https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [JSTL core](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Use [`<c:out value="${someString}"/>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) tag to display Strings. `<c:out>` escapes HTML characters so that you can avoid cross-site scripting, you can specify that by setting the attribute `escapeXml=true`. Another advantage is that you can also provide a default value in case the `value` evaluates to `null`.

You can also use `fn:escapeXml()` EL function. You need to include [JSTL functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) for that .

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Another possible way , will be build a custom [ELResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html).

> Enables customization of variable and property resolution behavior for EL expression evaluation.

[This blog](http://pukkaone.github.io/2011/01/03/jsp-cross-site-scripting-elresolver.html) provides a working example of how it can be done.

---

For the entire Spring MVC app , you can specify the escaping in the *web.xml*:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But then the escaping applies only to the `spring` tags , like :

```
<form:input path="formField" htmlEscape="true" />
```

Lastly , you can try the third-party library [XSSFilter](http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/xssflt.htm).

Comment: this is good, but i'd have to scan all outputs in my JSPs. Moreover a new person may not know that this is the proper way. Any automatic/global solution?

Comment: I have tried to set `htmlEscape="true"` on my form but it doesn't escape script tag,  any idea why?

Comment: Great. With  XSSFilter, there is now no excuse to use that bloated JSF.

Answer (score 1):

You can also control this behaviour at page level using `<spring:htmlEscape defaultHtmlEscape="true" />`

Comment: Look the answer of NINCOMPOOP.
"But then the escaping applies only to the spring tags."

Answer (score -1):

In JSP/Java You should use this code:

In JSP/HTML:

```
<c:out value="TR tag </tr> Script Tag <script>alert("hello Rahul")</script>" escapeXml="true" />
```