# Java/Jquery : Issue facing due to Double Quotes(") in String Value

Tags: java, jquery

In my JSP i am getting below value as string.

```
strFullContent:: 1BOOK OFFERS NO GUARANTEE OR WARRANTY THAT THE CRAFTS ARE WITHOUT ERROR. CRAFTS ARE PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND
```

In application below code is there.

```
input type="hidden" name="strFullContent" id="strFullContent" value="<%=objCraftsUploadDataBean.getStrFullContent() %>"/>
```

Now when I am printing value in JSP,complete value is getting printed. but when i am trying to get that value in js partial value is getting fetched.

```
var fullcontent =document.getElementById('strFullContent').value;
```

now this variable fullcontent contains only partial value.

```
fullcontent = 1BOOK OFFERS NO GUARANTEE OR WARRANTY THAT THE CRAFTS ARE WITHOUT ERROR. CRAFTS ARE PROVIDED
```

As per my understanding problem is due to " in value. But I don't know the solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526502/how-to-html-encode-in-the-jsp-expression-language , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919998/escape-all-strings-in-jsp-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Change your input and use single quotes there instead of double quotes for value since value also contains those

```
value="<%=objCraftsUploadDataBean.getStrFullContent() %>"
```

can be

```
value='<%=objCraftsUploadDataBean.getStrFullContent() %>'
```

Or you can escape them if you still want to use double quotes.

Comment: Escaping is the only *correct* solution, IMOHO. The data wasn't expected to contain a `"` and so it broke. In the future, data might contain `'` and so it will break again.

Comment: That's also mentioned in the answer.

Comment: It's mentioned as a very small footnote without the rational found in my comment.

Comment: Tried the solution given by Hanky. It worked. but User2864740 is also correct. Can you please let me know how to escape special character ?

Answer (score 0):

Worth a try

```
strFullContent = strFullContent.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

Comment: It would be better to replace `"` with `&quot;` - or, best(er), use existing escaping support.

Comment: This is not Working. Getting below exception.

Comment: ServletException in:/views/frame/CraftContent.jsp] Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 51 in the jsp file: /views/content/CraftUploadFive.jsp Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression 48: 49: 50: 51: "/> 52: 53: 54: An error occurred at line: 51 in the jsp file: /views/content/CraftUploadFive.jsp Invalid character constant 48: 49: 50: 51: "/> 52: 53: 54: Stacktrace:' org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 51 in the jsp file: /views/content/CraftUploadFive.jsp Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression 48

Comment: Do it on your String input